# Classification of quadratic non-etale $k$-algebras

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, and let $A$ be a quadratic $k$-algebra (i.e., $A$ has $k$-dimension 2).

If $A$ is etale, then either $A = k\times k$ or $A$ is a quadratic separable field extension.

If $A$ is nonetale, $A$ can be either $k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$, or a quadratic inseparable extension (which can only happen in characteristic 2).

Are there any other options? Are there weird alternatives to $k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2)$ that I'm missing?

Bonus question: I understand that the general classification of Artin local $k$-algebras is very complicated. Are there classifications in low degree? This question asks for degree 2. What about degree 3? 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x \in A \setminus k$. Then $\{1,x\}$ is a basis for $A$. So we can write $x^2+ax+b=0$ for $a,b \in k$. Thus we get $A\cong k[x]/(x^2+ax+b)$. If $x^2+ax+b$ is irreducible, this is a field extension and we are done. If $x^2+ax+b$ is reducible, there are two possibilities: it is the square of a linear polynomial or the product of two distinct linear polynomials. In the first case, a change of basis yields an isomorphism $A \cong k[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)$. In the second case, the Chinese remainder theorem yields $A \cong k\times k$.